GIT: bad diff line detection in code file
Suppose I have this code:
class Class1
    public property C1prop as string
end class

I commit this code, then I add a second class:
class Class1
    public property C1prop as string
end class

class Class2
    public property C2prop as string
end class

In some circumstances git diff gives me the following result:
  class Class1
      public property C1prop as string
+ end class
+
+ class Class2
+     public property C2prop as string
  end class

While committing this and then possibly reverting these changes doesn't screw up my code, I would prefer to commit this:
  class Class1
      public property C1prop as string
  end class
+
+ class Class2
+     public property C2prop as string
+ end class

because it's a more correct representation of what has been added.
Reading diffs would also be easier this way.
Is there a way to force git in this situation?
I use both the command line version and GitKraken gui.
Thank you

Tried it on a sandbox repo with the exact code sample you gave. Got the expected diff (second, more consistent one). But the question is interesting indeed, I've wondered myself about these unexpectedly complex/unnatural diff outputs in some cases.

This actually happens on code that I cannot share, I wrote this example just to explain the scenario. As you noticed this doesn't always happen, and there should be a way to fix it.

Have you tried filing a feature request? The idea is reasonable and you could actually code it so that for two equivalent diffs, one with leading/trailing is preferred over one with internal whitespace. Doing so would keep "connected" code blocks connected.

Note that this statement isn't relevant, "I would prefer to commit this", because you are committing that, since both versions of the commit are an equivalent state. The only difference is the algorithm diff is using to display it. I see this often and I agree it would be nice if it was a little smarter about which equivalent diff a human might like to see.

foreword : there is no such thing as "the diff" between two contents, generating a diff will always be subject to interpretation.

You may try your luck with the "histogram" diff algorithm:
git diff --histogram ...

# to set it as the default algorithm on your local machine:
git config --global diff.algorithm histogram

This setting drives the command line git toolbox.
For a separate GUI tool as gitkraken, check the documentation to see if it honors this setting or if it has a setting of its own.

Since diffs in git are always recomputed from content (git does not store "the patch that updates a file"), they also depend on the machine on which they are run.
For example: there may be a difference between the diff you see on your own local machine and the diff computed and displayed on your central git repo (github, gitlab, ...)
You would have to look into the available settings to compute diffs on the various platforms/machines where you use git.

You can also use git add --patch
